# which is recommended use getter or just equals in live data in view model android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel, android-livedata

I have view model and I use live data in encapsulation, which one is recommended to use and why?

```
private val _licenseStatusFromWebService = MutableLiveData<String?>()
val licenseStatusFromWebService: LiveData<String?> = _licenseStatusFromWebService 

private val _licenseStatusFromWebService = MutableLiveData<String?>()
val licenseStatusFromWebService: LiveData<String?>
    get() = _licenseStatusFromWebService
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It Does not matter which way you use it as long as the `MutableLiveData` you are referring to is a `val` and not a `var`, but if you are going to modify or reassign the `MutableLiveData` to something else the getter approach `get() =` will return the latest instance and equals approach `=` will return the initial instance.

Also, Kotlin internally builds a getter for every property you have so if you are choosing the equals approach `=` for the sole purpose of reducing code on production, it will amount to nothing.

Comment: You mean that if Mutable Live Data is val it doesnt matter, but if it is var, I must use get()

Comment: yes, but as you mentioned in other comments developer.android website has get() because if you keep using get() it won't matter even when you mistakenly reassign the said object. It is generally a best practice to use get() when typecasting an object to prevent getting older instances.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I thinks it can be correct answer.

Comment: I have second question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75017024/which-one-recommended-to-use-postvalue-in-io-thread-or-setvalue-on-main-thre

Answer (score 0):

**I think using an object directly is recommended way in ViewModel**

```
private val _licenseStatusFromWebService = MutableLiveData<String?>()
val licenseStatusFromWebService: LiveData<String?> = _licenseStatusFromWebService
```

*because, I am using this approach in some of my projects*

Comment: But in developer.android site, they used get() function but not explain why.

Comment: I think using objects is the best way. after all, it's up to you which method to use.

Answer (score 0):

It`s just to encapsulate mutable LiveData from immutable. As in UI you should use already prepared data from ViewModel to avoid modifying it from the UI directly.

```
private val _licenseStatusFromWebService = MutableLiveData<String?>()
val licenseStatusFromWebService: LiveData<String?> = _licenseStatusFromWebService
```

Comment: But in developer.android site, they used get() function but not explain why.

Comment: it is the same, it depends on your code style, in these two cases you will get the reference to the same object.